# How to know if a point belongs more or less to a circle?

Tags: geometry, coordinates, computational-geometry

I know the formula to know if a point is inside, outside and on a circle : https://math.stackexchange.com/q/198769 This quote explains that we must compare `d` to `r` (please read the quote, **it's only 5 lines**).

**But I just want to know if a point is ON a circle**. Moreover, and that's the real problem : **if a point is *a bit* inside/outside a circle, I want to consider it as ON the circle.**

How could I do that ? I tried to delimit `d-r` (ie. : the comparison) in a range. Example :

> if(d-r > -100 && d-r < 100) { point is on the circle }

It works, with -100 and 100, for circles with a little radius (ie. : ALL the points that are *a bit* outside/inside the circle are considered as being on the circle).

But for circles for a big radius, only SOME points are considered as being on the circle (ie. : only some of the points that are a bit outside/inside the circle are considered as being on the circle)...

**So I would want that ALL the points that are a bit outside/inside the circle are considered as being on the circle, independently of the circle's radius. How ?**

Comment: Your question *may* be specific to some programming language you trying to write code with. In current state of the post it is very hard to reason what could be causing your problems (which are likely due to misunderstanding of data types used in the code and they limitations).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your comparison for absolute difference might be written shorter as

```
if Abs(d - r) < delta (i.e. 100) ...
```

But seems you need relative difference depending on circle radius like this:

```
if Abs(d - r) / r  < reldelta (i.e. 0.001) ...
```

Answer (score 1):

From a probabilistic perspective, you could define a sort of distance map (as proposed by @Mbo) adopting the relative distance and use it to build a probability distribution on each point. The probability would represent a sort of likelihood of the point to belong to the circle. Intuitively, the closer the point, the more likely it is to be part of the circle. For example:

```
rel_d = (d-r)/r;

//  P(x on the circle) = 1 - rel_d 
if(rel_d < 1){
     P_on_circle = 1 - rel_d;
}else{
     P_on_circle = 0;
}
```